# How can I filter out a page in Google Analytics when the URL is empty?

Tags: google-analytics

When people go to the top page of my site, Google Analytics shows it in my reports as a simple forward slash:

```
/
```

I'm trying to get a set of results in the Analytics API to exclude the top page, but I don't know how to filter out this basically empty URL.

In the Google Analytics filter interface, I tried filtering the forward slash by escaping it:

```
\/
```

But this ended up filtering *every* page.

How do I filter results when the URL resource is just `/`?

Comment: You could add the start and end string delimiters: ^\/$

Comment: @nyuen, is it possible to replicate that in the filters in the API when accessing by PHP? Right now I'm filtering for pages that have more than 100 views, and I'd like to also filter out this blank URL. Something like `$filter = 'pageviews > 100 && URL != ^\/$';`

Comment: Presumably your home page has also a  title, so you might want to use that.

Comment: I got it! The filter I need is: `pagePath!~^\/$`